# Suma de una suma SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

Buenas tengo una consulta la cual me trae unos valores apartir de la funcion suma, quiero saber si hay forma de sumar esos valores. La consulta es la siguiente.

```
SELECT sum(a.Total_Venta+c.Intereses) as Total
FROM [SCEURIANGATO].[dbo].[TB_Ventas] a 
inner join [SCEURIANGATO].[dbo].[TB_VentaMicro] c on c.Id_Venta = a.Id_Venta
where a.Fecha > '20210501' 
and a.Estado in (1,2)
and id_tipo_de_venta = 8 
GROUP BY A.FECHA
order by a.Fecha
```

Los resultados que quiero sumar son los siguientes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muestra la salida que obtienes al realizar la consulta.

Comment: Bienvenido Alex Ortega a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Quita el `GROUP BY A.FECHA order by a.Fecha` y deberías tener la suma total

Comment: @PatricioMoracho exactamente eso iba a decir. Al hacer lo del group by ya está separando los registros en bloques y solo se suman cada bloque. Si no hace lo del group by ya la suma va a ser de todos esos registros.